# Filter array with includes failing

Tags: javascript, arrays

This behaves as expected and I get back "banana"...

```
let like = ["banana"];
let fruits = [
    { name: "apple" },
    { name: "banana" },
    { name: "pear" },
];

let fruits2 = fruits.filter((f: any) => like.includes(f.name));
console.log(fruits2);
```

But this fails...

```
ticketDetailsSubset2 = ticketDetailsArray.filter(
 (i: any) => !excludeTickets.includes(i["stl19:TicketNumber"][0])            
);
```

The array for excludeTickets is simply this...

```
0: ["0017522827238"]
```

I am looping through the ticketDetailsArray which includes 3 objects ...

- first object contains - `stl19:TicketNumber: ["0017522827238"]`
- 2nd object contains - `stl19:TicketNumber: ["0017522827238"]`
- 3rd object contains - `stl19:TicketNumber: ["0017522827239"]`

I should get back only the 3rd object as the 1st two objects are in the excludeTickets. Even though I'm a beginner I threw in the fruit example to prove that I am on the right track. I also manually tried doing

```
!excludeTickets.includes("0017522827238")
```

and it still didn't work. Everything is returned. I have a similar .filter piece of code with another conditional check and it works. What's the difference - the .includes ?? so I'm guessing includes is not meant to do what I think it does but then again the fruit option works??

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. By making it reproducible, you'll need to reconstruct at least enough to get it failing in the same way as your current code, which can help you identify what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`excludeTickets` is a 2-dimensional array (notice the square brackets around `excludeTickets[0]`), not an array of strings. You need to flatten it.

```
flatTickets = excludeTickets.flatMap(el => el);
ticketDetailsSubset2 = ticketDetailsArray.filter(
    (i: any) => !flatTickets.includes(i["stl19:TicketNumber"][0])            
);
```

Comment: brilliant. I'm a newbie - would never have thought of this. I'll read up on flattening..Thanks Barbar